# Select highest and lowest date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I now have a query like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`Datum`, '%e %M') AS `DATE`, tag AS `TAG`, value AS `VALUE`, addedTs as `addedTs`
FROM dailyMessage
INNER JOIN `psttodo-uit`
ON dailyMessage.Code = `psttodo-uit`.`Hostess Code`
WHERE Code = "010"
```

I know get a result like this:

```
DATE        TAG             VALUE                   addedTs 
4 April     calls           3                       2014-04-04 20:32:39
4 April     endTS           2014-04-04 22:40:55     2014-04-04 22:40:55
4 April     kmstart         32                      2014-04-04 18:34:37
4 April     kmstop          34434334                2014-04-04 18:35:30
4 April     startTS         2014-04-04 18:35:00     2014-04-04 18:35:00
4 April     visits          6                       2014-04-04 22:40:53
5 April     endTS           2014-04-05 01:37:41     2014-04-05 01:37:41
5 April     kmstart         30                      2014-04-05 01:37:41
5 April     startTS         2014-04-05 01:13:25     2014-04-05 01:13:25
5 April     visits          1                       2014-04-05 01:13:23
7 April     authorizations  4                       2014-04-07 22:34:37
7 April     calls           9                       2014-04-07 23:18:28
7 April     endTS           2014-04-07 23:35:32     2014-04-07 23:35:32
7 April     kmstart         42                      2014-04-07 18:10:43
7 April     kmstop          55                      2014-04-07 19:37:42
7 April     startTS         2014-04-07 10:45:18     2014-04-07 10:45:18
7 April     visits          6                       2014-04-07 23:35:31
8 April     endTS           2014-04-08 11:24:28     2014-04-08 11:24:28
8 April     startTS         2014-04-08 11:24:28     2014-04-08 11:24:28
```

Now I would also like to select highest date from the psttodo-uit table. This is what I want to do:

In the `psttodo-uit` table there is a `Hostess Code` (`== Code in my WHERE clausule`). There is also a `afgewerkt tablet datum` field in the table of datetype `datetime`.

The dates variate like so:

```
2014-04-04 11:41:22
2014-04-03 17:20:01
2014-04-01 15:12:08
2014-04-07 22:20:47
2014-04-08 11:21:18
```

Now when I do a query I would like to select the max time of the specific day. I tried it like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`Datum`, '%e %M') AS `DATE`, tag AS `TAG`, value AS `VALUE`, addedTs as `addedTs`, MAX(`afgewerkt tablet datum`) AS `TimeSorE`
FROM dailyMessage
INNER JOIN `psttodo-uit`
ON dailyMessage.Code = `psttodo-uit`.`Hostess Code`
WHERE Code = "010"
```

But then I got this:

```
4 April calls   3   2014-04-04 20:32:39 2014-04-09 11:49:42
```

Two problems:

- I only get one result back
- The date is not 4 April

Is there someone who can help me with this?

**UPDATE:**

What I've tried:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`Datum`, '%e %M') AS `DATE`, tag AS `TAG`, value AS `VALUE`, addedTs as `addedTs`, MAX(`afgewerkt tablet datum`) AS `TimeSorE`
FROM dailyMessage
INNER JOIN `psttodo-uit`
ON dailyMessage.Code = `psttodo-uit`.`Hostess Code`
WHERE Code = "010"
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`Datum`, '%e %M')
```

Gave me this:

```
4 April calls   3   2014-04-04 20:32:39 2014-04-09 15:46:04
5 April endTS   2014-04-05 01:37:41 2014-04-05 01:37:41 2014-04-09 15:46:04
7 April authorizations  4   2014-04-07 22:34:37 2014-04-09 15:46:04
8 April endTS   2014-04-08 11:24:28 2014-04-08 11:24:28 2014-04-09 15:46:04
```

But I need them all (with all tags).

Comment: use MAX() and MIN() for date

Comment: You only need to add GROUP BY to your last query, for example add `GROUP BY tag`.

Comment: Still giving me one result ... Only the row with the MAX date...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`Datum`, '%e %M') AS `DATE`, GROUP_CONCAT(tag) AS `TAG`, value AS `VALUE`, addedTs as `addedTs`, MAX(`afgewerkt tablet datum`) AS `TimeSorE`
FROM dailyMessage
INNER JOIN `psttodo-uit`
ON dailyMessage.Code = `psttodo-uit`.`Hostess Code`
WHERE Code = "010"
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`Datum`, '%e %M')
```

IF you need the result set as seperate rows try this

```
SELECT A.DATE ,A.CODE,TAG,addedTs,TimeSorE
(
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`Datum`, '%e %M') AS `DATE`,dailyMessage.Code AS CODE
  MAX(`afgewerkt tablet datum`) AS `TimeSorE`
    FROM dailyMessage
    INNER JOIN `psttodo-uit`
    ON dailyMessage.Code = `psttodo-uit`.`Hostess Code`
    WHERE Code = "010"
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`Datum`, '%e %M')
) A , dailyMessage B

WHERE
A.CODE = B.CODE AND
A.DATE = B. DATE_FORMAT(`Datum`, '%e %M')
```

Comment: GROUP BY clause must contain all columns from SELECT list or those columns must be in AGGREGATE functions

Comment: My mistake, I refer to standard SQL, but MySQL has extension of GROUP BY clause to group over non-aggregated columns.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely works for me:

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(`Date`, '%e %M') AS `DATE`, 
  tag AS `TAG`, 
  value AS `VALUE`, 
  addedTs as `addedTs`, 
  MAX(`afgewerkttabletdatum`) AS `TimeSorE`
FROM Test
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`Date`, '%e %M')
```

Here is an example:

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6657/3)

Comment: That's only giving me 4 rows (4,5,7,8 april). I need all of the rows of a day because they have different tags. So for 4 april I need to have 6 rows (like in my topic) with each MAX_DATE the same..

Comment: I don't need the addedTs MAX but the afgewerkt tablet datum MAX. I added it and add addedTs to GROUP BY. And I'm getting always the same max time and it isn't correct..

Comment: remove all but the one column from group by clause and then try again

Answer (score 0):

I think this gonna work:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`Datum`, '%e %M') AS `DATE`,
       tag AS `TAG`,
       value AS `VALUE`,
       addedTs AS `addedTs`,
       t2.`TimeSorE`
FROM dailyMessage
INNER JOIN (SELECT `Hostess Code`,
                   MAX(`afgewerkt tablet datum`) AS `TimeSorE`
            FROM `psttodo-uit`
            GROUP BY `Hostess Code`) t2 ON dailyMessage.Code = t2.`Hostess Code`
WHERE Code = "010"
```